# How to capture image with webcam at Nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I want to capture image with webcam at Node.js.
I implemented a simple http communication server as node.js, and I want to capture the image with a webcam when the packet comes in. The period at which the packet arrives is 2s.

```
var NodeWebcam = require( "node-webcam" );
var opts = {
    width: 1280,     height: 720,     quality: 100,     
    frames: 60,    
    delay: 0,  
    saveShots: true, 
    output: "jpeg",
    device: false,
    callbackReturn: "location",
    verbose: false 
};  
var Webcam = NodeWebcam.create( opts );
request.on('end', function(){
        var parsedQuery = querystring.parse(postdata);
        var result = parsedQuery.Rssi;
        var board = parsedQuery.Board;
        else if(board == "44")
        {
            var fs2 = require('graceful-fs');
            var file2 = '44Board.txt'
            fs2.open(file2, 'a+', function(err,fd){
                if (err) throw err;
                fs2.appendFile(file2, result, function(err){
                    if (err) throw err;
                });
                fs2.close(fd);
            });
            Webcam.capture( "test_picture" + cn,  function( err, data ) {
            });
            cn++;
        }
}
```

The node-webcam module was used, which was designed to take photos every 2s and save them in the form of test_picture0.jpeg, test_picture1.jpeg, but the actual capture period was over 5 seconds.
As a result, several files were skipped in the format test_picture0.jpeg, test_picture2.jpeg, and test_picture4.jpeg.

I want to reduce delays like this. Can't I capture it without a delay?

Comment: Consider this alternative - https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-camera

Comment: @Eccentric291 The expo-camera module is taken with the front and rear cameras of the mobile device, and my experiment is taken with the webcam of the computer, so it is not expected to be available.